# Transform not working on block span element

Tags: html, css

I was just modifying a friends site **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/FilmFestivalToGo/html/V4/)**, and basically it has the following menu:

[image]

Now the code for the css Menu looks like so:

HTML:

```
<a class="" href="">
    <span class="hamburger">                
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

The `span`'s inside the `.hamburger` class have a display property of `block` , but when i try to apply the following style:

```
.hamburger > span:nth-of-type(1) {
        transform: rotateX(45deg);
    }
```

The transform is not applied. Why ? I am aware that the HTML element needs to be display `inline-block` or `block` to beable to transform it.

Comment: That does work as is ... use `rotate` instead of `rotateX` and you'll see

Comment: Or use `rotateZ` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works, just not noticeable on horizontal lines

```css
.hamburger {
  font-size: 500%;
}

.hamburger:hover>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}

span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 1s;
}

span span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="" href="">
  <span class="hamburger">                
    <span>1 -</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: When don't post answers when there is no issue, we vote to close

Comment: @LGSon English is my foreign language. I easier to give code than to explain in words

Comment: I already posted words, as comment, and there is no problem with the question, it works, so no need to post an answer saying it works

Comment: @LGSon when I write the code in the snippet I don't see comments